# jquery replace part of text with html content

Tags: jquery, replace, replacewith

How can I replace part of a text with html?

```
  <span class="squaremeter">3000m2</span>

   var content = $(".squaremeter").text().replace(/\[m2\]/g,'m<sub style="font-size:0.5em;">2</sub>')
   $(".squaremeter").html(content);
```

The above does not work...

Comment: What do you mean by "does not work"? Please share things you've debugged and tried to solve the issue, and be specific about the problem.

Comment: Your regex seems off. What do you want the regex to do exactly?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/wf2mstsu/

Comment: Im trying to replace m2 with squaremark symbol where 2 is in subscript

Comment: Do you understand what your regex does and what Vohuman's does?